# Check type with boolean property?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm very aware of type checking, but have found myself in a unique situation and I'm beginning to question whether I'm within best practices.  Hopefully the veteran comments will give me some direction and things worth thinking more deeply about.  And, to be honest, it's not that what I have will not work, but as I'm making some other changes I'm wondering what the pitfalls might be and whether I should change tactics.  There doesn't seem to be a lot out there (in fact I havent' seen anything as basic type checking takes the majority of the search results).

I have a situation where I'm developing a bill of material interface system. In this system, the following class diagram applies:

[image]
This is generically speaking, but the point here is that there are only three concrete types worth concerning.  Because it's easy to set property values in the constructors of the objects, I had defined (generically speaking again of course) the IMaterial interface as so:

```
public interface IMaterial
{
    bool IsCommodity { get; }

    bool IsAssembly { get; }

    bool IsUnclassified { get; }

    ...
}
```

Originally, the thought was that the object graph has very little room to change, performance is improved through a preset boolean value, and I don't have to worry about breaking various other principles by type checking concrete types.

So for example, I can do this...

```
bool hasCommodities = materialCollection.Any(item => item.IsCommodity);
bool hasAssemblies = materialCollection.Any(item => item.IsAssembly);
bool hasDescriptionOnly = materialCollection.Any(item => item.IsUnclassified);
```

or this...

```
if (bomMaterial.IsAssembly)
{
    symbol = new BomAssemblySymbol();
}
else
{
    symbol = new BomItemSymbol();
}
```

instead of this...

```
bool hasCommodities = materialCollection.Any(item => item is ClassifiedItem);
bool hasAssemblies = materialCollection.Any(item => item is Assembly);
bool hasDescriptionOnly = materialCollection.Any(item => item is UnclassifiedItem);
```

or this...

```
if (bomMaterial is Assembly)
{
    symbol = new BomAssemblySymbol();
}
else
{
    symbol = new BomItemSymbol();
}
```

So in my case, the interface's use of properties means less dependency on concrete types in the implementation detail.  But then again, it begs the question, what if another type does come along?  What's the best answer here?  And is there a pattern that maybe I'm overlooking and should be considering for this?  And if anyone is wondering why the consuming code cares, it's because with the CAD system, there is a single command the user interacts with that in turn leverages these objects.  I can't create separate commands for them just because of the single line of code difference.
**Update**
Here's a more complete example showing how the CAD-side seems to bottle neck processes.  The TryGetMaterialInformation() method prompts the user in the CAD system for specific input.  The SymbolUtility.InsertSymbol() method just wraps a common set of user prompts for inserting any symbol and then inserts it.

```
public override void Execute()
{
    IMaterial bomMaterial = null;
    bool multipleByReference = false;
    Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

    if (!TryGetMaterialInformation(out bomMaterial, out multipleByReference))
    {
        ed.WriteMessage("\nExiting command.\n");
        return;
    }

    IBlockSymbol symbol;
    if (bomMaterial.IsAssembly)
    {
        symbol = new BomAssemblySymbol();
    }
    else
    {
        symbol = new BomItemSymbol();
    }

    if (multipleByReference)
    {
        SymbolUtility.InsertMultipleByReferenceSymbol(symbol, bomMaterial);
    }
    else
    {
        SymbolUtility.InsertSymbol(symbol, bomMaterial);
    }
}
```

From SymbolUtility

```
    internal static void InsertSymbol(IBlockSymbol symbol, IMaterial material)
    {
        ICADDocumentDTO document = new CADDocumentDTO();
        Editor ed = document.ActiveDocument.Editor;

        //Get the insert point
        Point3d insertPoint = Point3d.Origin;
        if (!CommandUtility.TryGetPoint("Select insert point: ", out insertPoint))
        {
            ed.WriteMessage("\nExiting command.\n");
            return;
        }

        //Insert the object    
        using (ISystemDocumentLock documentLock = document.Lock())
        {
            CreateSymbolDefinition(symbol, document);

            symbol.Insert(insertPoint, material, document);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is anything stopping you from having an `IItem`, `IAssembly`, `IClassifiedItem` and `IUnclassifiedItem`?

Comment: With your current structure, if any new property comes, you will have to change every single class. That's horrible

Comment: Why are the DTOs interfaces?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Heck no, Code Review doesn't want anything to do with this question.

Comment: @Mast This fits exactly the help page of Code Review: "If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas… Best practices and design pattern usage"

Comment: Please take a look at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/52915) and Code Review's [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before making such recommendations again @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: @Mast Maybe you need to re-review that help center, because it fits every criteria under "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the question being on stackoverflow. But, as is often the case, it's almost impossible to draw a connection between the literal question at the top of the post and anything that follows. I don't know what "Checking a type with a boolean property" means. Do you mean how do you check what type something is? You do it the same way whether or not it has a boolean property.

Comment: @Corak Actually, I meant to show that.  I do have an IItem, IAssembly, IClassifiedItem, and IUnclassifiedItem as well.  Sorry about that.  I have them, but for their individual purposes.  I updated this post with the right image.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've seen that help center often enough I've just about memorized it. Might want to take a look at my activity over there, I'm somewhat familiar with what is and isn't done there. This is a generalized question about an approach, not about the actual code used. That and other reasons make it fail the "However" checklist.

Comment: @bjhuffine - great, so use them as checks. Usually you don't want to check for concrete types but you want to check what *kind* of object you have and what you can do with it. Hence interfaces. Imagine someone creates a subclass of `Assembly` and lets `IsAssembly` return `false`. Would the consuming code still work correctly? -- Would it with `item is IAssembly`?

Comment: @Scott Hannen I tried stripping DTO out of the examples to generalize them.  Missed one.  I'm trying to maintain separate from the Application layer as it also has interfaces with another system.  I just called them DTO for this purpose as I can also read similar objects from a database storing standard objects.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto and Mast:  I can move this to Code Review if I need to.  I looked but didn't see it when I first posted this.  It is a specific question though, but the code does work.  My fear is more or less am I creating future problems with this approach and try to learn from this.

Comment: @bjhuffine I see no problems with leaving it here. if others disagree, they should vote to close with a valid close reason instead of trying to migrate something that shouldn't be migrated to the target mentioned.

Comment: @Corak Since it's IMaterial that defines the IsAssembly property, then any class created will be required to define whether IsAssembly is true or not.  So I think I'm covered there.  If the subclass inherits Assembly, then by default it will return the correct value.  Interesting thought though.  If the subclass was a variant of Assembly, then would there be a need to distinguish it different from the basic assembly?  That's in part why I also asked about patterns and application because there's too many ifs...

Comment: @ScottHannen If you have a suggestion for the title I'm game to update.  One of the challenges of posting on SO has always been coming up with a concise but descriptive title that also meets the requirements of the forum to which one is posting.

Comment: I know. Sometimes I edit the questions and it's not easy to come up with something that describes it clearly in a few words. Perhaps "Should classes or interfaces have properties that indicate their concrete types?" (If that describes it accurately)

Answer (score 1):

If you have properties like `IsCommodity`, `IsAssembly`, and `IsClassified`, they should describe some sort of logical property that can be ascribed to an instance. They should *not* tell the consumer what the concrete type is.

The reason is that a consumer of `IMaterial` should neither know nor need to know about any concrete type that implements `IMaterial`.

*If* those properties actually indicate the concrete types, then all those properties accomplish is type checking, and they will lead to casting objects back to their concrete types, which defeats the purpose of creating an abstraction (interface.)

It looks that way to me since you're considering the properties as a direct alternative to type checking.

The alternative is that instead of the consumer looking at the class properties and deciding what to do or not to with the class, the consumer just tells the class what do to (calling a method) and the implementation of the class itself determines how to carry that out.

Comment: Not to mention the little fact that adding a new type would mean changing the base interface hence changing every implementer.

Comment: @ScottHannen So in my second example where I'm creating a symbol object, both those implement an interface IBlockSymbol and the code following it basically calls symbol.Insert().  So technically, this doesn't care.  However, the actual physical objects stored in the CAD drawing do care and are thus represented by separate IBlockSymbol objects.  That's why I ended up checking types there.  How would it have been best to handle that then?  I can't add Insert() to the Assembly object as that breaks its responsibility.  It's basically a glorified data carrier.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I agree and honestly something I didn't immediately think about until now.  At first, I was thinking of these as more descriptive properties and avoiding unnecessary type checking.  Now I'm beginning to think it's worked out to more or less straight up type checking.  But again, these are glorified data objects (even stored in another assembly so that they can be used when retrieving data from a database).  But from the CAD perspective, the CAD commands tend to bottle neck processes more requiring that we know their types.  I'll update my example.

Comment: @bjhuffine Does this involve the user inserting objects? If so, then you could have a property indicating whether items can be inserted. Within your UI it might be used to indicate whether or not the user can insert something. It's not that boolean properties to indicate behaviors are bad. It just gets muddy when they indicate concrete types.

Comment: @ScottHannen I don't know if it helps explain the problem, but I expanded the code example to show how the processes are bottlenecked through this user interaction.

Comment: The problem may be this: `SymbolUtility.InsertSymbol` vs `SymbolUtility.InsertMultipleByReferenceSymbol`. That means that something outside of the symbol needs to know how to insert another symbol into it. Instead perhaps that should be a method of the symbol itself. You just call `symbol.Insert` and it knows how it should handle that insert.